# bootstrap 5 navbar exclude navbar-text from navbar-toggler

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar

My navbar looks like this on large screens:

[image]

On smaller screens the `navbar-toggler` is active and only the button for the toggler is shown. Is it possible to exclude a `navbar-text` from the toggler? I would like to display the Kontostand (marked red) always on smaller screens:

[image]

The code for the navbar:

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggler" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#mainMenu" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

<div id="mainMenu" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <div class="nav navbar-nav">
      <a class="nav-link active" href="willkommen.php"><span class="fas fa-home"></span> Startseite</a>
       <?php
        //Check Session
        echo "<a class='nav-link' href='news.php'><span class='fas fa-file'></span> Neuigkeiten <span class='badge badge-pill badge-danger'>3</span></a>";
        ?>
    </div>
    <div class="nav navbar-nav ms-auto">
      <?php
            //calculate Kontostand
                echo "<span class='navbar-text'><strong>Aktueller Kontostand: € <input disabled type='text' size=1.5 class='inputKonto' style='border:none transparent; outline:none; background: transparent; font-weight: bold;' id='Kontostand' name='Kontostand' value='".number_format((float)$Summe, 2, ',', '')."'</input></strong></span>";
                echo "<a class='nav-link' href='logout.php'><span class='fas fa-sign-out-alt'></span> Abmelden</a>";
      ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Non-collapsible text in Bootstrap 5 navbar

##### Case 1. On the right side

If all the items on the left should be collapsed, and the text on the right should remain visible at any screen width, then:

1. Move the block with the text **outside** the block with the `navbar-collapse` class.
2. Place it **before** the collapsible block to keep text stationary while menu items expand and collapse on a narrow screen.
3. Add one of the [order classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/utilities/flex/#order) to move the text block on the right side of the navbar on the wide screen.

Here is a working example based on code from the [Bootstrap documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/navbar/).

https://codepen.io/glebkema/pen/VwWeyxG?editors=1000

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="navbar-text text-white order-lg-last">
      Non-collapsible text
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 2</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link 3</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

##### Case 2. Between menu items

If the collapsing elements are on either side of the text, then you can duplicate the block with the text inside and outside the `navbar-collaps` block to show the second text only on narrow screens when the menu is collapsed.

https://codepen.io/glebkema/pen/jOwWYKW?editors=1000

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="navbar-text text-white d-lg-none">
      Non-collapsible text
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Left 1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Left 2</a>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <div class="navbar-text text-white me-2 d-none d-lg-block">
        Non-collapsible text
      </div>

      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Right 1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Right 2</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```